# Como utilizar "position:absoluted" corretamente?

Tags: html, css

boa noite.
Estou construindo uma aplicação com phonegap e estou com seguinte problema. Tenho uma div com uma imagem de background com "position:absoluted". Gostaria de criar um componente a baixo dessa div...porém ele fica sempre em cima da imagem.

```css
#map_canvas {
    position: absolute; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #6495ed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas">MINHA DIV</div> 
    <div>TESTE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu quero que o "TESTE" fique em baixo do map_canvas.
Agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

> Um detalhe, o correto é `position:absolute` e não `position:absoluted`.

Você colocou `z-index: -1;`, isto é negativo ou seja vai descer uma camada de nível.

Use o `z-index: 1;` ou maior:

```css
#map_canvas {
    position: absolute; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #6495ed;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas">MINHA DIV</div> 
<div>TESTE</div>
```

Agora se você quer dizer no campo de visão, ou seja não um sobre o outro, mas um acima do outro na disposição, então não use `position: absolute;`, use `float:`, `clear:` e algumas vezes `display: table;` ou `display: inline-block;`:

```css
#map_canvas {
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    background-color: #6495ed;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas">MINHA DIV</div> 
<div>TESTE</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer funcionar da seguinte forma: http://jsfiddle.net/zVBDc/760/

Comment: @LucasCarnevalli Não entendi porque esta usando `position:absolute;` aonde não é necessário. Me parece o mesmo resultado do segundo código que coloquei na minha resposta, mas você mudou a largura e a cor da borda, apenas isto.

Comment: O código que enviei agora não é o que estou utilizando, é um exemplo de solucionar o problema. Eu estou trabalhando com google maps, e o mapa só está aparecendo quando eu defino um div com absolute... Dai eu tive que fazer um meio alternativo para conseguir contornar.

Comment: @LucasCarnevalli acredito que você não tenha entendido, independente de você aplicar `position: absolute` ou não, se ter cor vermelha ou azul, boa ou sem borda, o que importa é o efeito que quer atingir, e o "efeito" que você criou não tinha a necessidade do `position:absolute;` e basicamente o segundo código que postei trás o mesmo "efeito" necessário. Agora se existe alguma coisa que difere no "efeito" (não me refiro ao código) então poderia evidenciar pra entender, pois se não são o mesmo efeito, então é porque não foi explicado necessariamente na tua pergunta o que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que colocar um `margin-top: 100px`, que corresponde ao tamanho do quadrado.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ue6yzqu/

```css
#map_canvas {
    position: absolute; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #6495ed;
}

.teste {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas">MINHA DIV</div> 
    <div class="teste">TESTE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ue6yzqu/... para a margin seu mapa tem de ter um top: 0;

Comment: Ao invés de comentar, você pode clicar em [edit] embaixo da sua resposta para incluir mais informações.